# Solr - Sort by field character count and lexicographical value

Tags: java, solr

So basically I have the following problem,
I have 3 documents in my index:

```
test activ1

test activ9

test activ15
```

And when I sort by their title I want to get:

```
test activ1

test activ9

test activ15
```

But What I actually get is:

```
test activ1

test activ15

test activ9
```

the title fieldtype is define like so:

```
<fieldType name="title" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have tried to look into Similarity class to change lengthNorm but I cant get the field value in it to compute the field length.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** query used:

```
select?q=title:test*&sort=title+asc
```

Comment: what is the query you are using? Can you provide that.

Answer (score 0):

> The sort parameter arranges search results in either ascending (asc) or descending (desc) order. The parameter can be used with either numerical or alphabetical content. The directions can be entered in either all lowercase or all uppercase letters (i.e., both asc or ASC).

Solr is returning the results sorted alphabetically. Alphabetically, when you will compare the `test activ15` and `test activ9`, `test activ15` will come first because `1` comes first then `9`.

What you are expecting or thinking is as numerical values, `9` is smaller then `15` but solr is treating them as String (alphabets). The analyzer chain, you have configured, will output the token in text form. So solr would not be able to treat numbers in the text separately. So I think, output is correct.

From the documentation: Solr sort feature requires `field` to be analyzed by `KeywordTokenizer`, so it will generate one single term. Basically, it expect the term to completely either numeric or alphabetic, later is the case for your data.

---

**Edit:**
You might need to write your own custom sorting logic. Please this [post](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2011/05/custom-sorting-in-solr-using-external.html). It have some information about writing custom sorting logic using `FieldComparatorSource` and `FieldComparator`.

Comment: Check the post mentioned in the answer. It might help you.